# Maximum request length exceeded. IIS 8.0 reading pcap file ?c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

In case of winform we use openfiledialogue and get the file path but i am using **asp.net c# web forms** now

get the filepath server side actually i want to read Pcap file and i want to open a file dialogue that filter **Pcap file** and give their path server side using c sharp i have tried all trick like

```
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

but this does not give me path of file server side

on click button the error appears

> > Maximum request length exceeded.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length
>   exceeded.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() +9813126
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() +63
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +160
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm() +69
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +13
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() +9810059
>   System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
>   +95    System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +69    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +130

using IIS 8.0

Answer (score 4):

For the security purpose, web browser does not allow to show physical path of the file. It returns only file name with help of 
  **FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName**

Comment: IIS 8.0 fil limit exceeds

Comment: for IIS 7.0 or above, you need to set **maxAllowedContentLength**

Answer (score 0):

using the following code

```
      string name = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

get the path of file and adding in webconfig

```
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600"/>
```

resolve max length error in IIS 8.0 configuration in config section